# how to get a directory listing like windows explorer

Tags: c#, treeview

I am building a treeview control and want to start with a listing like windows explorer displays:

My Documents
My Computer
 - (expand one level)
 bob(C:)
 recovery(D:)
 DVD (E:)

My Network places...
And so on, how do you get that kind of information from Directory info?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a good example: http://blog.andweaccelerate.com/2010/11/wpf-explorer-treeview-with-selectedpath.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explorer shows special folders, as well as logical drives.

Logical drives you obtain using [Directory.GetLogicalDrives Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getlogicaldrives.aspx)

Slecial folders can be "mapped" to actual paths using [Environment.GetFolderPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)

Once you have the locations of all "root nodes", you can enumerate their "directories" using [Directory.GetDirectories Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) or [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx)

Comment: I need to try this and I will get back to you but it seems right from a quick look, thanks.